# tkinter output returns strings as a dict

Tags: python, tkinter, window, output

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

def output():

    yield 'The %s line' % ('first')
    yield '\n'
    yield 'The %s line' % ('second')


def reply():
    showinfo(title='Log size', message=(list(output())))

window = Tk()
button = Button(window, text='Get info', command=reply)
button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

which returns [this](http://prnt.sc/eq994c).
How can I make the output looks better as:
**The first line

The second line**

I have tried to get **message** as list(i for i in output()), but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a list! Just `join` generator's content as string:

```
def reply():
    showinfo(title='Log size', message=''.join(output()))
```

And there's no dicts at all, let the curly braces not bother you. Try to print your list:

```
>>> list(output())
['The first line', '\n', 'The second line']
```

So if you really loves lists, you can `join` your return list:

```
def reply():
    showinfo(title='Log size', message=(''.join(list(output()))))
```

Another note, as you see that you can treat generators like list, but it's not completely true, try this:

```
def reply():
    gen = output()
    showinfo(title='Log size', message=''.join(gen))
    showinfo(title='Log size', message=''.join(gen))
```

So as you see, it's some sort of temporary list, that lets you take off each item one at a time or all of them only once. So if you want to preserve information - list is a good idea!

More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python).